# Why is this pointing to the application process when called inside a function?

Tags: node.js

Writing the following code inside my Node application:

```
Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
    let daysOfWeek = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
    return daysOfWeek[this.getDay()]
}

(async () => {
    ...
    ...
    ...
})()
```

I get this.getDay() is not a function. when I log this in this context I get the process object:

```
    Object [global] {
global: [Circular],
process:
process {
    title: 'node',
    version: 'v10.12.0',
    versions:
    { http_parser: '2.8.1',
        node: '10.12.0',
        v8: '6.8.275.32-node.35',
        uv: '1.23.2',
        zlib: '1.2.11',
        ares: '1.14.0',
        .....
        .....
        .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Before writing a self calling async function you always need to put a semi-colon. The code will work like this:

```
Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
    let daysOfWeek = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
    return daysOfWeek[this.getDay()]
}; //You need to put a semi-colon before writing a self calling async function

(async () => {
    ...
    ...
    ...
})()
```